# Is there a way I can set up my Windows 8 tablet as a graphics tablet for another machine?

Tags: windows-8, remote-control, touchscreen

I have a Windows 8 Tablet with a pressure sensitive stylus. Is there any way I can use this as an input device for my desktop computer (running Windows 7) and use as a fully supported graphics tablet (not just mouse) in applications such as Photoshop?

Comment: what is your desktop computer running? os... etc...

Comment: @Logman, edited to clarify.

Comment: Just to confirm - Win8 or WinRT?

Comment: @Karan, the tablet is running the full Windows 8 (not RT) on an Intel Atom architecture

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I want to use my Dell VP8 as a graphics tablet for my desktop.